# Write.table with new line after a pattern in each cell for Excel for friendly output

Tags: r

I have my data like this:

```
tt <- structure(list(A.T = structure(c(`4` = 2L, `5` = 3L, `6` = 1L
), .Label = c("2015(1583)", "2273(1876)", "4916(3954)"), class = "factor"), 
    A.G = structure(c(`4` = 2L, `5` = 1L, `6` = 3L), .Label = c("18645(2960)", 
    "6394(1409)", "8601(1275)"), class = "factor"), A.C = structure(c(`4` = 1L, 
    `5` = 3L, `6` = 2L), .Label = c("451(173)", "482(230)", "860(349)"
    ), class = "factor"), C.T = structure(c(`4` = 1L, `5` = 3L, 
    `6` = 2L), .Label = c("3885(3148)", "4042(3049)", "7772(5955)"
    ), class = "factor"), C.G = structure(c(`4` = 1L, `5` = 3L, 
    `6` = 2L), .Label = c("162(108)", "171(107)", "333(239)"), class = "factor"), 
    C.A = structure(c(`4` = 2L, `5` = 3L, `6` = 1L), .Label = c("1825(1481)", 
    "2118(1743)", "3449(2557)"), class = "factor"), G.T = structure(c(`4` = 2L, 
    `5` = 3L, `6` = 1L), .Label = c("2019(1794)", "2571(2336)", 
    "4538(4086)"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("4", 
"5", "6"))
```

Say if I write this table as `write.table(tt, "mynewcsv.csv", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)` and then open `mynewcsv.csv` in Excel, it would look like this:

[image]

However, I want my excel table to look like this:

[image]

What do I need to do so that `mynewcsv.csv` in Excel looks the way I want?

Comment: I guess you need to do this in excel rather than R.

Comment: Perhaps `quote=T` does work to "capture" the new line within a "cell"

Comment: @RYoda - you are right, have updated my answer to show this.  Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert a newline character using `sub()`:

```
write.csv(sapply(tt, function(x) sub("(?<=\\d)(?=\\()", "\n", x, perl = TRUE)), "mynewcsv.csv",  quote = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

After opening in Excel, **you need to highlight the cells and enable "Wrap text"** for it to display correctly.

The end result should be:

[image]